# Expose one jar to many wars in ear structure

Tags: java, maven, war, wildfly, ear

I have one maven project with the ear structure and I'm deploying the ear on the wildfly 9.0.0

I have one jar with jpa doing the persistence and I have 3 wars that use this jar, if I import this jar on the pom in one of this wars this is ok, but if I import this jar in two wars the CDI doesn't work.

What I really want to do is to expose this one jar to all wars in the ear without importing in every war pom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Stop the server
2. Open the server configuration file. (standalone/configuration/standalone.xml)
3. Locate the EE Subsystem Configuration element in the configuration file. The profile element of the configuration file contains several subsystem elements. The EE Subsystem element has the namespace of urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2.
4. Replace self-closing tags if necessary
5. Add ear-subdeployments-isolated element
6. Start the server

Note that this disables Subdeployment Module Isolation for All Deployments and not only for this deployment.
[documentation for all deployments](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Disable_Sub-Deployment_Module_Isolation_for_All_Deployments1.html)

If you want for this specific deployment only you should:

1. Add the deployment descriptor file
2. Add the ear-subdeployments-isolated element

   [documentation for specific deployment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Disable_Subdeployment_Class_Loader_Isolation_Within_a_EAR.html)

This is valid for JBOSS EAP which has pretty similar behavior with JBOSS wildfly.

EDIT: As @Will T has correctly stated in comments in the wars dependencies of the jar with the scope `<scope>provided<scope/>` should be added.

Comment: I've already put this configurating, my problem is how to configure the poms to provide the jar to all wars without import in the wars poms

Comment: Are you sure you have to explicit declare dependencies in the poms of each sub-deployment? I  think that setting the  ear-subdeployments-isolated to false makes the wars implicitly dependent to the jar you want.

Comment: From documentation: 
If the ear-subdeployments-isolated is set to false, then the classes in web.war can access classes belonging to ejb1.jar and ejb2.jar. Similarly, classes from ejb1.jar can access classes from ejb2.jar (and vice-versa).If the ear-subdeployments-isolated is set to true then no automatic module dependencies between the sub-deployments are set up. User must manually setup the dependency with Class-Path entries, or by setting up explicit module dependencies. 
(https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-AutomaticDependencies)

Comment: You want to ensure that the pom for each war lists that jar as <scope>provided<scope/> as this will provide the class for compilation, but will not include in the war. You can then make sure your ear contains the jar

Comment: With the element ear-subdeployments-isolated and <scope>provided<scope/> solved my problem. Thanks